# Conductivity of molten or aqueous salts

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, conductivity

1. If there is a 1M aqueous solution of 1 liter NaCl (aq), and the molar conductivities of the solution and the chloride ions were found to be $x$ and $y$ respectively, is it accurate to say that the molar conductivity of sodium ions is $x-y$? If not, how else can I calculate the molar conductivity of sodium ions from the given data? (I'm just using NaCl as an example)
2. Is there any way to compute the molar conductivity of an ion without any experiments?

Comment: it would be x+y since they are ions and that is what is needed. Check Kohlrausch's law (feels related).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot determine individual ion's molar conductivity at 1 M. The ions are not independent enough. Kohlrausch's law of independent migration of ions does not apply, it only applies at a fictitious concentration of 0 M NaCl! This value is found mathematically by extrapolation to zero concentration

> Is there any way to compute the molar conductivity of an ion without
> any experiments?

Yes, if you look up the tables of molar conductivities at infinite dilution, then you can determine molar conductivities of individual ions.